# C# Linq compare only date from a datetime property

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have the following Linq to Entity:

```
var details = Uow.EmployeeAttendances.GetAllReadOnly()
    .Where(a => a.EmployeeId == summary.EmployeeId && a.Timestamp == summary.Date)
    .ToList();
```

`summary.Date` is just the date part so the value is like this: '2014-07-20 00:00:00'

The problem is that `a.TimeStamp` is a DateTime field with both date and time.

> So the above query always return empty

Any way I can convert `a.TimeStamp` just to Date so I can compare apples with apples?

The error that I get is:

```
The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities
```

Appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

`DateTime` fields have a [`Date` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date(v=vs.110).aspx), so we can simply do:

```
var details =
    Uow
        .EmployeeAttendances
        .GetAllReadOnly()
        .Where(a => a.EmployeeId == summary.EmployeeId
            && a.TimeStamp.Date == summary.Date)
        .ToList();
```

Comment: This will not work in the Linq to Entities (As mentioned in the question).

Answer (score 3):

The right solution is:

In Entity Framework 6, you have to use DbFunctions.TruncateTime.

```
  var dates = Uow.EmployeeAttendances.GetAllReadOnly()
                .Where(a => a.EmployeeId == summary.EmployeeId && System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime(a.Timestamp) == attendanceDate)
                .OrderBy(a=> a.Timestamp)
                .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to using DbFunctions.TruncateTime, you can simply do the following:

```
var from = summary.Date;
var to = summary.Date.AddDays(1);
var details = Uow.EmployeeAttendances
  .GetAllReadOnly()
  .Where(a => a.EmployeeId == summary.EmployeeId && a.Timestamp >= from && a.Timestamp< to)
  .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
     string f = summary.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
     summary= Convert.ToDateTime(f); // time at 12:00 start date
     var details = Uow.EmployeeAttendances.GetAllReadOnly()
    .Where(a=>a.EmployeeId== summary.EmployeeId &&
    a.Timestamp == summary).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use DateTime.Compare
for example

```
var details = Uow.EmployeeAttendances.GetAllReadOnly()
.Where(a => a.EmployeeId == summary.EmployeeId && DateTime.Compare(x.Timestamp .Date, summary.Date) == 0).ToList();
```

or use EntityFunctions

```
    var details = Uow.EmployeeAttendances.GetAllReadOnly()
.Where(a => a.EmployeeId == summary.EmployeeId &&  EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(x.Timestamp)==  EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(summary.Date)).ToList();
```

Comment: There are way better answers than yours, because they are well formatted. So please consider editing your question to proper format it. Thats what the `code snippet thingy` is for, that code gets displayed as code and not just plain black and white unformatted text.